# what is the use of repository and why do mvc developers create repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, repository

I have seen in many **MVC project** concept of **Repository** but i dont know why many mvc developers use **repository**.

What is the advantage of creating **repository** ?

What is the use of **repository**?

If it improves **performance** then how it improves **performance**?

Are there any **guidelines** to create **repository**??

Comment: Repository is nothing but a class act as a data model.its upto you.you can create the separate repository for each table.

Comment: I am asking for advantage of creating repository and how it imporves performance?

Comment: its purpose is to write method for **CRUD** and use it in controller instead of writing data access code in controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of repositories is referred to [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

It is best to read the [book](http://www.domaindrivendesign.org/books/evans_2003) about DDD by Eric Evans.

In short, the repository allows you to hide details of loading objects from a database. This is especially useful for complex composite objects.

Comment: does it increase performance r it is just to seperate data access layer from business logic???

Comment: the link you have given does not give any explaination regarding repository

Comment: Repositories is just one of concepts of domain-driven design. I recommend you to read the book.

As a quick start you can read this [article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/03/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns/).

Comment: take a look at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925257/best-repository-pattern-for-asp-net-mvc?rq=1

Comment: The author refers to Microsoft documentation about repositories, but his examples are not repositories.

Or, maybe, the term repository has too many meanings.

If your domain classes are well-mapped to relational tables, just use Entity Framework. If not, you'll need to construct each composite object (Evans calls them aggregate roots) from several tables and maybe from several databases even. Hide this construction in repository.

If you are using SQL, but think about NoSQL in future you fix the interface of "getting data from somewhere" in your repositories.

Comment: You may take a look at this implementation example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616188/7389293

Answer (score 1):

1. Advantage of using Reository : Clean code, strongly typed view.
2. Use of Repository: Repository class may expose DB Table structure or it may be view model that can be passed to view to render data.
3. No performance gain.
4. Guidelines

   i. Create repository to represent table in database, columns will be properties of that repository.

   ii. Create repository which to bind strongly typed view. Its properties will be all attribute you want to display using view.

Comment: you have any reference like step by step guide to create repository?

Answer (score 0):

@lmad, what you described in you guideline is not repository - it's just a view model in context of MVVM pattern. Repository is a pattern for data access logic, where you define your own contract for data access. In C#, for instance, once you defined repository interfaces, then distinct implementations of every interface can be easily changed by each other.
@Maria Pithia, it will be enough for you: [msdn - repository description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). Hope, this will help.

Comment: is this link explaination is in context to mvc??

Comment: repository pattern is just design pattern, it can be applied where you want to formalize, or to structure, your data access logic... In all application types.

Comment: does it increase performance r it is just to seperate data access layer from business logic???

Comment: Obviously, second one. Please, read article mentioned above. It has  all knowledge you need.